# Reason behind undefined 'this' in React Event Handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

We all know that `this` will be undefined according to the given code of React. We have many solutions for this problem, like binding, arrow function, etc. I want to know the reason behind this behavior. Please, ***explain the reason for the behavior*** of `this` reference, instead of solutions.

```
class Foo extends Component {

   clickHandler() {
      console.log(this);
   }

   render() {
      return <button onClick = {this.clickHandler}> Click Me </button>;
   }

}
```

Comment: In fact, I think that ```this``` must be a reference to the button created. This is what it's behavior is in plain javascript. But here, in this code, ```this``` is undefined, unexpectedly. I want to understand its reason.

Comment: taker look here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Comment: @MuhammadMuaaz go through this https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480 you will get more clarification

Comment: Thank-you, @Harish. This link helps a lot in playing with ```this```. Thank-you to @Vahid Akhtar also.

Answer (score 0):

1)this.clickHandler=this.clickHandler.bind(this) is returns a new function,in which reference to 'this' will refer to the function this is the way of saving the current value of this which is scope during the call to the constructor so that it can be called later the function is called.
if our function dont require access to the state at your component then sure you dont need to bind this.

2)arrow functions automatically bind this, that’s why we don’t need to use .bind() method.